# Node.js - res.sendFile - Error: ENOENT, stat - Even though path is correct

Tags: node.js, express, path

Here's my folder structure :

- Root Folder

  - ...
  - ...

    - ...
  - app.js
  - escape_iframe.html
  - ...

from within `app.js` I'm doing :

```
res.sendFile('escape_iframe.html' , {root : __dirname});
```

and the error I'm getting is :

```
Error: ENOENT, stat '/app/escape_iframe.html'
```

which I guess is a horrible way of saying that the file can't be found in the path provided ?

Anyway, as you can tell I simply want to serve a file that is a `sibling` of `app.js` (which is the file form which the `res.sendFile(...` call is being made)

I also tried : `res.sendFile('escape_iframe.html');` and I got : `path must be absolute or specify root to res.sendFile`

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paths specified with a `.` are relative to the current working directory, not relative to the script file. So the file might be found if you run node app.js but not if you run node folder/app.js.

To make a path relative to the script, you must use the `__dirname` variable.

```
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/path/to/escape_iframe.html');
```

Comment: Based on the folder structure I've provided you with and what you've just said, I should then do `res.sendFile(__dirname + '/escape_iframe.html');` correct ? but I've already done that and I get `Error: ENOENT, stat '/app/escape_iframe.html'`

Comment: ok that's embarassing - apparently it was all due to a typo (`escape_iframe` instead of `escape-iframe`) - Apologies for wasting everyone's time!

Answer (score 1):

Path specified with `.` are relative to the path and any number of forward slashes are truncated as single slash. You might get this error when the process `node filename.js` is not able to locate the filename.
https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_enoent_no_such_file_or_directory

My suggestion would be ::

```
var path = require('path')
//process.cwd() returns the current directory of the project
res.sendFile(process.cwd(),'/path/to/escape_iframe.html');
```